# Nested svg not expanding to fill parent container

Tags: html, css, svg

According to this [article](http://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/nesting-svgs/) and also [this article](http://sortino.co/writing/creating-a-responsive-svg) if you do not specify the width and height of the inner SVG it should automatically expand the width and height of the outer SVG.

This HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <svg>
<path d="M470.3,204.3 l-1,-2.3 -0.5,-1.6 -2.9,-1.6 -4.8,-1.5 -2.2,-1.2 
-2.6,0.1 -3.7,0.4 -4.2,1.2 -6,-4.1 -2.2,-2 -10.7,0.6 -41.5,-2.4 
-35.6,-2.2 -4.3,43.7 33.1,3.3 -1.4,21.1 21.7,1 40.6,1.2 43.8,0.6 h4.5 
l-2.2,-3 -2.6,-3.9 0.1,-2.3 -1.4,-2.7 -1.9,-5.2 -0.4,-6.7 -1.4,-4.1 
-0.5,-5 -2.3,-3.7 -1,-4.7 -2.8,-7.9 -1,-5.3z" id="a state" 
fill="#000000" />
  </svg>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Results in this

[image]

Note:  I am using latest Chrome browser.

As you can see the inner SVG is not expanding to fill the outer SVG as stated in the above articles, even though the height and width have not been specified on the inner SVG. I have tried messing with the `preserveAspectRatio` atrribute and to no avail(and from my understanding it shouldn't matter).

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help and if I am missing anything or need to include more info please let me know.

Comment: It is the height and width of the parent. What do you expect the rendering to look like?

Comment: I'm expecting the state(the internal svg) to expand to the size of the blue area(the external svg). Instead it remains the same size regardless of the external svg. According to what I have read a nested svg will automatically expand to fill it's parent. This is not the case with my example; I don't understand if I am missing a property within the svg that makes this so.

Comment: It does but the content won't unless you supply a viewBox.